# Question regarding $n$-regular graph being partitioned into paths

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question regarding an $n$-regular (simple) graph, and why it cannot be partitioned into paths of length $n+2$, for example.

For instance, if I have a $7$-regular simple graph, then I assume I have an $8$ vertex graph (since an $n$-vertex graph is $(n-1)$-regular). Then, if I needed to partition into paths of at least $9$ edges, that is impossible because a path cannot repeat vertices more than once (and we only have $8$, not $9$). Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: An $n$-regular graph does **NOT** have to have precisely $(n+1)$ vertices. So your assumption that a $7$-regular simple graph has to be a graph on $8$ vertices is not correct. The complete graph $K_n$ is indeed $(n-1)$-regular, but that's just one example of regular graphs.

Comment: $K_{n,n}$ is $n$-regular and has $2n$ vertices, for example.

Comment: @zipirovich thank you for the correction - I was wrongly assuming that this example had to be a complete graph. I am still confused about how to show why the 7-regular simple graph cannot have path of length 9

Comment: @saulspatz thank you, that is true. do you have any suggestion about how to show that the path cannot be 9 then (for the 7-regular example)?